# Get list of all instantiated views from application view in ember

Tags: ember.js

I have defined an application view that handles click events. When someone clicks outside of a view, the application click function fires and sets all child views 'active' property to false. I am selecting specific views by assigning 'viewName'. This works great for a couple of my views, but I have hit a snag with a view that is instantiated after the page renders (it is in a conditional that can become true in the template). I would expect the applicationView to pick this up, but it doesn't. How can I get a list of all of the views instantiated in the app (preferably without using the internal API)?

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application',
  click: function () {
    this.get('childViews').filterProperty('viewName','applicationViewClickChild').setEach('active', false);
  }
});

App.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({   
    templateName: 'views/person',   
    active: false,   
    viewName: 'applicationViewClickChild',   
    click: function () {
        if (this.get('active')) {
            this.set('active', false);
        } else {
            this.set('active', true);
        }
        return false;   
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Get list of all instantiated views from application view in ember

You can get to a list of instantiated views via the [Global views hash](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_views) `Ember.View.views`. For example:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application',
  click: function () {
    var keys = Em.keys(Ember.View.views);
    var views = keys.map( function(key) { 
      return Ember.View.views[key]
    });
    views.filterProperty('viewName','applicationViewClickChild').setEach('active', false);
  }
 });
```

Comment: @Mike thank you very much. This worked perfectly for what I was trying to do. After too many hours this is a perfect solution. If youre ever in Ireland I owe you a beer.